# How does foursquare animated its map view from a table header to full screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, mapkit, foursquare

I'm looking at implementing a mapview in the uitableview header and got that part covered, but does anyone know how foursquare have done the animation to full screen map and back to map+uitableview?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain the map view is actually a table view section header. I think the section header is transparent and the map view is just behind the table view.

Then, animating to full-screen is simply animating the table view away.

Comment: Tried this angle but it doesn't seem possible to get a transparent table view section header. @Benoit.

Comment: Make sure to set the tableview's background to be transparent as well.

Comment: Solved. Thanks Benoit for discussing this with me.

Comment: @drisse: You should post your code so that this question has a self-contained answer.